# How to remove thin lines and small points from qgis raster

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to digitize the roads of a raster map to vector format using QGIS and GDAL preferably. By using the Raster Calculator I have been able to extract the roads and contour-lines from the raster to another raster by selecting pixels of the right color. The problem now is that I don't want the contour-lines, just the roads. The difference here is that the contour-lines are much thinner than the roads.

I have been trying to use Sieve and Proximity without much luck. I think I want something similar to Shrink in ArcGIS or maybe use different settings. Here is my start image which has gone through Raster calculation and a Proximity filter.[image: Extracted roads and contours]

Answer (score 2):

you could use morphological mathematics for that (opening will extract objects larger than the structuring element )

in QGIS 2.2 Add the toolbox window (processing > toolbox)

then use Orfeo Toolbox > Image filtering > Binary morpholigical operation

Note that you could also use closing to connect your line segments.

With QGIS 2.1, OTB is available from sextante